# Inserting data with Geometry field

Tags: database, geo-data

I am trying to insert data which contains a POINT field. I am using the $wpdb->insert method but when generating the SQL it is wrapping the POINT in quotes.

```
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->base_prefix . 'points';

$Data = array(
    'Title' => $this->Title,
    'gPoint' => sprintf("POINT(%s,%s)",$this->Lng, $this->Lat),
    'Lat' => $this->Lat,
    'Lng' => $this->Lng
);

if (!$wpdb->insert($table,$Data))
    throw new Exception($wpdb->last_error);
```

This is the SQL generated. If I take the quotes from around the POINT field, the query will run.

```
INSERT INTO `wp_points` (`Title`, `gPoint`, `Lat`, `Lng`) VALUES ('My Marker', 'POINT(0.2566251,51.0581515)', '51.0581515', '0.2566251')
```

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `%s` in your sprintf statement, $wpdb->insert() will automatically apply single-quotes.

You want to use `%f` for float, or `%d` for int/digit.

Comment: Thanks, but by the time it gets to the $wpdb->insert, the sprintf is gone and just left with this : POINT(0.2566251,51.0581515) .    Then the insert wraps the whole lot in quotes which is the problem, as the database tries to insert a string instead of a POINT.